# is DataTable.FindBy() Threadsafe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, datatable

I have a DataSet with Multiple DataTables and i'm retrieving rows from it with FindBy method.
My application is Multi-Threaded, and my question is, is it thread safe or shoul'd i cover all of my methods with a lock which will make my app not a Muli-Threaded app...

Comment: I can't find any mention of the FindBy method on MSDN for either [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)s or [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx)s.  Can you post a code sample please?

Comment: Also, multithreaded applications that require locking on shared resources are still multithreaded applications...

Comment: @smudge: with a lock in _every_ method there would not be much threading.

Comment: @Henk locking *every* method would not be the correct way to make your application thread safe.  Locks are for shared resources, beit un-thread safe variable access, file access, socket access, etc...  Lock resources, not the entire workflow

Comment: true, but this application in particular retrieves information from datasets and that's about it.

Answer (score 2):

> ## DataTable Class
>
> Thread Safety
>
> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

This should answer your question.

Comment: In principle, Yes, this should answer the question. But FindBy is a generated method in typed Datasets, not totally clear if it's covered by this promise.

Comment: Yoda, I've gone over MSDN and saw that sentence but online I found a guy who says that select on DataTables is not hread safe.

Here is the link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/ddcdac9d-35e7-4b9f-a367-242bf60c42f2/

Answer (score 0):

You shall protect any Create/Update/Delete operations with synch logic. For performance reasons do not synchronize Reads.

FindBy does not *sound* like it is modifying data. From the other hand as pointed by Matan

> [Selecting rows using Select method on
>   DataTable (yes, this can modify the
>   DataTable by creating a new index on
>   it).](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/ddcdac9d-35e7-4b9f-a367-242bf60c42f2/)